# how to run specific code automatically excel

Tags: excel

i have created this macro, and also a button to run this macro, what i want is, whenever the value in
`column F` becomes greater than zero, macro should run on its own, without me clicking the button to run it
how to do this? what changes do i need to make?

```
Sub Macro1()
    For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
      If Range("F" & i).Value > 0 Then
        Range("E" & i).Value = Range("D" & i).Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

edit:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
      If Range("F" & i).Value > 0 Then
        Range("E" & i).Value = Range("D" & i).Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: If column F contains formulas, then the `Worksheet_Calculate` event. Otherwise, the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: as column doesnt contain any formula i used Worksheet_Change, it isnt working @BigBen

Comment: Did you put that code in the sheet code module? Then, you should check if `Target` `Intersect`s column F, and probably toggle `EnableEvents` as well. Also use `Me` instead of `ActiveSheet`

Comment: Looks like you've tried to create your own event. If you do it properly the first line is `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`.

Comment: i have added private keyword , still no change,

Comment: added code in sheet code module. EnableEvents made true, used Me instead of ActiveSheet,

Comment: Insert a breakpoint and then step through when your code is triggered. This will happen when you change any cell.